# Rotation of join of two different rods when one is rotated

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

Two cylinders A and B made of same material and having same length of radii $r$ and $2r$ are soldered coaxially. The free end of A is clamped and the free end of B is twisted by an angle theta. The twist (angle in degrees) at the junction for equal length will be?

The answer is 16/17 * theta. But how?

Comment: Assuming the cylinders are of equal length?

Comment: Yes equal length. I think torque will be same for the junction and the rod.But then how to go forward?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Damn it , this is not a homework question.

Answer (score 0):

I assume "coaxially" to mean that the centre of one face of the smaller cylinder and the centre of one face of the large cylinder are the same point.

I assume the angle would be four-fifth since the total volume is five times the volume of the smaller cylinder, you are twisting the thicker of the two, and the thicker one has four times the volume of the smaller one.

Comment: The answer is 16/17 * theta. But how ?

Answer (score 0):

Find the rotational stiffness $C$ of each section and calculate $\Delta \theta = \frac{\tau}{C}$ with $\tau$ the applied torque.

The rotational stiffness of a uniform rod of length $\ell$ is

$$ C = \frac{G J}{\ell}$$

where $J$ is the polar moment of inertia. For a solid rod this is $J=\frac{\pi}{2} R^4$